# Is it possible to create multiple swagger documentation pages on one system Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, swagger

I implement the swagger into the larvel project. I would like to create several api swagger documentation on one server. Each documentation pages will be for another system that provides own api. This server collects all data in one db of different systems. Is it possible to create multiple swagger documentation pages on one system?

Forexample:

www.webdomain.com/api/system1

www.webdomain.com/api/system2

www.webdomain.com/api/system3

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

you Can Use springFox to group the services into one document.
[here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320770/springfox-docket-per-controller-not-working-in-spring-boot/52290823#52290823),

in the example i am creating Docket bean dynamically, and group them per Controller.
you can choose you own strategies.