# Swagger how to group rest methods (API documentation)

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I used Jhipster (spring boot + angular) to generate a web aplpication.

Currently it generated two swagger groups on the swagger view:

http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs?group=management : shows only management API

"@RequestMapping("/management/audits")"

http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs : that shows me all API methods except management

"@RequestMapping("/api/")"

I want to create a new swagger group that will contains a few rest methods. I've searched on documentation but could't find anything :

https://github.com/indrabasak/swagger-deepdive/wiki/Multiple-Swagger-Groups

Aparently on the official documentation what they do is use Springox and create some "Docket" classes . But JHipster app do not have any "Docket" class, even so i can see 2 groups, but the thing is that i don't know how to edit it or create new one seems to be so hard-coded.

What i have related to swagger on my JHipser app

application.yml :

```
swagger:
    default-include-pattern: /api/.*
    title: API
    description: API documentation
    version: 0.0.1
    terms-of-service-url:
    contact-name:
    contact-url:
    contact-email:
    license:
    license-url:
```

Noode module: \myproject\node_modules\swagger-ui

Angular view : \myproject\src\main\webapp\swagger-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <link href='./dist/css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='./dist/css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='./dist/css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='./dist/css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='./dist/css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <script src='./dist/lib/object-assign-pollyfill.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/handlebars-4.0.5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/lodash.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/swagger-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/jsoneditor.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='./dist/lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <!-- Some basic translations -->
    <!-- <script src='lang/translator.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='lang/ru.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='lang/en.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var springfox = {
                "baseUrl": function() {
                    var urlMatches = /(.*)\/swagger-ui\/index.html.*/.exec(window.location.href);
                    return urlMatches[1];
                },
                "securityConfig": function(cb) {
                    $.getJSON(this.baseUrl() + "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", function(data) {
                        cb(data);
                    });
                },
                "uiConfig": function(cb) {
                    $.getJSON(this.baseUrl() + "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", function(data) {
                        cb(data);
                    });
                }
            };
            window.springfox = springfox;
            window.oAuthRedirectUrl = springfox.baseUrl() + './dist/o2c.html'

            window.springfox.uiConfig(function(data) {
                window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
                    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
                    validatorUrl: data.validatorUrl,
                    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
                    onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {
                        initializeSpringfox();
                        if (window.SwaggerTranslator) {
                            window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
                        }
                        $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
                            hljs.highlightBlock(e)
                        });
                    },
                    onFailure: function(data) {
                        log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
                    },
                    docExpansion: "none",
                    apisSorter: "alpha",
                    showRequestHeaders: false
                });

                initializeBaseUrl();

                $('#select_baseUrl').change(function() {
                    window.swaggerUi.headerView.trigger('update-swagger-ui', {
                        url: $('#select_baseUrl').val()
                    });
                    addApiKeyAuthorization();
                });

                function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
                    var authToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jhi-authenticationtoken") || sessionStorage.getItem("jhi-authenticationtoken"));
                    var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken, "header");
                    window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("bearer", apiKeyAuth);
                }

                function getCSRF() {
                    var name = "XSRF-TOKEN=";
                    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
                        var c = ca[i];
                        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
                        if (c.indexOf(name) !== -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
                    }
                    return "";
                }

                function log() {
                    if ('console' in window) {
                        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
                    }
                }

                function oAuthIsDefined(security) {
                    return security.clientId
                    && security.clientSecret
                    && security.appName
                    && security.realm;
                }

                function initializeSpringfox() {
                    var security = {};
                    window.springfox.securityConfig(function(data) {
                        security = data;
                        if (typeof initOAuth === "function" && oAuthIsDefined(security)) {
                            initOAuth(security);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            function maybePrefix(location, withRelativePath) {
                var pat = /^https?:\/\//i;
                if (pat.test(location)) {
                    return location;
                }
                return withRelativePath + location;
            }

            function initializeBaseUrl() {
                var relativeLocation = springfox.baseUrl();

                $('#input_baseUrl').hide();

                $.getJSON(relativeLocation + "/swagger-resources", function(data) {

                    var $urlDropdown = $('#select_baseUrl');
                    $urlDropdown.empty();
                    $.each(data, function(i, resource) {
                        var option = $('<option></option>')
                        .attr("value", maybePrefix(resource.location, relativeLocation))
                        .text(resource.name + " (" + resource.location + ")");
                        $urlDropdown.append(option);
                    });
                    $urlDropdown.change();
                });

            }

        });
    </script>
</head>


<body class="swagger-section">
<div id='header'>
    <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
        <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io">swagger</a>

        <form id='api_selector'>
            <div class='input'>
                <select id="select_baseUrl" name="select_baseUrl"></select>
            </div>
            <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

/myproject/webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
            secure: false
        }],
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('target/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loaders: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'awesome-typescript-loader'
            ],
            exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060'
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ]
});
```

Other links that I've checked:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/333

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/841

https://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/

http://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/

https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/

Comment: JHipster swagger config is not in generated code, it's in jhipster server-side library but you can override it see https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/tree/master/jhipster-framework/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/apidoc

Comment: The docket configuration in the JHipster server lib is done by autoconfiguration but you can override it by providing your own config have a look at the springfox docs.

Comment: if You would like to consider a solution using SpringFox Docket, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320770/springfox-docket-per-controller-not-working-in-spring-boot/52290823#52290823) in this example i am creating Docket Beans Dynamically by scanning @RestController annotation and group them per controller.